# Backbone destroy no server communication

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, coffeescript, slim

this is my logout click event:

```
logoutClicked: (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log 'userPanel.logoutClicked -> event', event
  console.info App.session
  App.session.destroy
    wait: true

    success: (model, res) ->
      console.log 'session.destroy.success -> model/res', model, res

    error: (model, res) ->
      console.log 'session.destroy.error -> model/res', model, res
```

this is my session model:

```
class App.Model.Session extends Backbone.Model

  initialize: ->
    console.log 'Session.init'

  urlRoot: '/session'
```

and this is my slim backend route:

```
$app->delete('/session', function () {
  session_unset();
  exit(true);
});
```

When i trigger the logoutClicked event all is working fine, but i can't see any server communication (no DELETE or GET to /session...) through my firebug..

Firebug output:

```
userPanel.logoutClicked -> event Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=18807379, altri elementi...}
Session { cid="c1", attributes={...}, _changing=false, altri elementi...}
session.destroy.success -> model/res Session { cid="c1", attributes={...}, _changing=false, altri elementi...} null
```

as u can see no DELETE request fired... and i receive a null res from my session.destroy success callback...
I'm new on Backbone, any suggestion? Maybe i have to setup Backbone.sync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call Model.destroy(...) on a new Model (which Model.isNew() === true). .destroy(...) won't do anything.

Reference:

- Model.isNew() http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-67
- Model.destroy() http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-63

One way to "force" destroy to be called is to manually set Model's ID to be not NULL, like...

```
App.Session.set('id', '_session_id_');
```

However, when you retrieve App.Session, its ID should already be set to the session ID. In that case, when retrieving a session from the server, you may want to do this step manually.

---

Side Note

If you want to call your ID attribute as `sessionID` instead of just id, you can also override the default `idAttribute` on `Backbone.Model`.

```
App.Session.Model
  idAttribute: 'sessionId'
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, now I see my session.destroy trigger to  /session/:id DELETE request, I have to change my php route to "$app->delete('/session/:id'.." or there's a way to trigger the DELETE request without the id?

Comment: You can override App.Session.Mode's isNew method to return false. That should do it!

Answer (score 2):

does App.session have a ID?

only model with a id attribute can be destroy.

in other words, you need to save first.